Main entry point function is (potentially) recursive
When attempting to use Frama-C's WP prover, by passing in the following:
frama-c -lib-entry -main foo -wp foo.c

I am given the error: [wp] User Error: Main entry point function 'foo' is (potentially) recursive.
Here are the contents of foo.c:
int foo(void)
{
    return 1;
}

int main(/*int argc, char *argv[]*/)
{
    return foo();
}

It seems that the WP plugin detects that the elected main function foo is called elsewhere, and thus assumes a potential for recursion. When the call to foo in main is commented out, there is no such error.
My question is thus: what is the precise meaning of this error? Furthermore, how may I inform the plugin that this is in-fact not the case?

The message appears because the function that is known to be the main entry point (foo) is called in the program (syntactically). Currently, it is not possible to silence this warning.
I'd suggest creating an issue for this on the public GitLab of Frama-C.

Understandable, and I shall do that. Many thanks for your reply.

C has no concept of an "elected main function". The main function is literally main. It has special status (e.g. returning from the initial call to main ends the program). Only main has that special status; foo doesn't. The important assumption here is that main has a hidden caller, i.e. the OS itself.
Frama-C allows you to pretend that another function is main. This transfers the assumption of the hidden caller. I.e. you just told Frama-C that there's a hidden caller of foo, in addition to the explicit caller. And under the reasonable assumption that everything in a program is callable, the regular function main in your program can be assumed to be callable from the entry point foo.
You solve this warning by not lying to Frama-C. The entry point of your program (from which all other functions can be called but which itself is only externally callable) is really main.

That was a really long-winded way of saying "don't do that." Thanks for your input, anyway. It is appreciated.

"You solve this warning by not lying to Frama-C" in some respects, you are right (my attempt is far from "proper"), so it's perhaps best to consider what I am trying to accomplish as a "dirty hack"; nothing more, nothing less.
